# Cannot download geth

Tags: go-ethereum

I tried to install the Geth for windows from the downloading page of go-ethereum https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/. However, the page stays pending "Retrieving packages from release server..."
then it displays "Failed to load releases!"
How can I solve this problem or can I get the Geth from another source?

Comment: It is working now, perhaps it was a temporary glitch.

Comment: Still not working. No information, you can just try to build the go implementation:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum

Answer (score 1):

https://gethstore.blob.core.windows.net/builds/geth-windows-amd64-1.13.12-02eb36af.exe
this is the link that is working for me.
Should work for you.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

you can download the installer by this mirror in git hub https://github.com/EthFans/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Geth-Mirror